# GWT 2.6.0 how to enable Internet Explorer 6/7 permutation

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, gwt-compiler

Release Notes GWT 2.6.0: 
"The ie6 permutation (which also handles IE 7) is now disabled by default. Support for IE6 and IE7 will be removed in the next major GWT release." 
Official relase Notes: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0

By default IE6 permutation is disabled. But how I can enable the ie6 permutation to make my application work with ie6 and ie7?

Secound question: is the module.xml file the only way to enable the permuation. What's about a flag for the gwt compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable ie6 permutation with in your module descriptor by adding this line of code:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" values="ie6" />
```

Comment: At the moment I have no entry in my module descriptor for any browser. So I need only one entry for ie6?

Comment: Yes, that should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I thought we had it documented somewhere but anyway, just add this to your gwt.xml:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
```