# The value ie6 was not previously defined

Tags: gwt, gxt

Getting error as:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
Loading inherited module  com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
[ERROR] The value ie6 was not previously defined.
```

To solve this i added `extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6"` in my gwt.xml. But this is throwing below error.

```
[ERROR] Element 'extend-property' beginning on line 13 contains unexpected attribute 'value'
[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an older version of GXT with a newer version (2.6.x or 2.7) of GWT.

If you are using GWT 2.6.x, you can enable the ie6 permutation. Take a look here:

[GWT 2.6.0 how to enable Internet Explorer 6/7 permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876765/gwt-2-6-0-how-to-enable-internet-explorer-6-7-permutation/21877101#21877101)

If you are using GWT 2.7, you need GXT  2.3.1a/3.1.2.

Comment: So you mean to say GXT 3.0.6 doesn't support GWT 2.6.0 ?

Comment: GXT 3.0.6 will support GWT 2.6, but you have to enable the ie6-Permutation. With GWT 2.6 the ie6 permutation is disabled by default. GXT 3.0.6 needs this permutation to work correctly.

Comment: How to enable ie6 permutation?
I used extend-property name="user.agent" value="ie6"  
but not solving for me
server call is failing .

Comment: I don't think that this problem is related to the property.

Comment: GXT 3.1.2 has no more dependicy to the ie6 property.

Comment: you are correct. Does GXT 3.1.2, GWT 2.6.0 support IE11? In official anouncement they have mentioned upto IE 10.

Comment: If youe Base GWT version is lesser than 2.6.0 - then you need GXT jar version lesser than 3.0.1

If you base GWT version greater than or equal to 2.6.0 then you need to add GXT jar version 3.1.X

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem in my project. This issue because of GXT jar file version. If you are GWT-2.6 or above version you should use GXT-3.1.x version jar file only. Otherwise you will get the same error.

GXT-3.0.1.jar file will support up to GWT-2.5.x version.