# GWT compilation failed in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gxt

guys i am trying to make small app using gxt but it gives me GWT compilation failed and then `[ERROR] Line 96: Value 'ie6' in not a valid value for property 'user.agent'` appears in the console 
here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD GWT 2.7.0//EN"
"http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">

 <module rename-to='gxt_project'>

 <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

 <!-- Other module inherits -->
  <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />

 <!-- GXT stylesheet -->
 <stylesheet src="reset.css" />

 <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
 <entry-point class='com.sencha.gxt.project.client.GXT_Project' />

 <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
  <source path='client' />
  <source path='shared' />
  </module>
```

and

```
public class GXT_Project implements EntryPoint {

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    TextButton textButton = new TextButton("Verify GXT Works");
    RootPanel.get().add(textButton);
    textButton.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox("GXT Works.");
        messageBox.show();
      }
    });

}
 }
```

also here is the project trace
[project trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zoI0.png)

any help would be appreciated .. thanks a lot

Comment: Sencha GXT 3.0.1 does not officially support GWT 2.7.0. (http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/getting_started/Versions.html) The latest supported GWT version is 2.5.1. And take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876765/gwt-2-6-0-how-to-enable-internet-explorer-6-7-permutation/21877101#21877101

Answer (score 0):

[GWT 2.7.0 does not support ie6](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0_RC1), but GXT 3.0.1 uses it in itself .gwt.xml (`com/sencha/gxt/core/Core.gwt.xml` etc).

You should upgrade GXT version or downgrade GWT version.

See Also: [GXT 4.0 Guides | GWT and GXT Versions](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/getting_started/Versions.html)